# Is there a description of cellular automata in form of sheaves?

Tags: reference-request, sheaf-theory, cellular-automata

Cellular automata are defined through rules in a local neighborhood and sheaves, as far as I understand, can be used to glue local data to global data. Has there been any effort to bring those two things together hoping to get some understanding of CA through the use of sheaves?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your background is, but anyway, the short answer is yes:

[check out this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.08086.pdf)

If you are interested, there is a fascinating new "movement" in applied category theory named **COMPOSITIONALITY**, which strives to understand complex systems as assemblages of smaller ones via applied categories (particularly [operads](https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/5969/operadiccompositionality-simons.pdf)).

https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/5969/operadiccompositionality-simons.pdf

Comment: thanks. is there any interesting finding regarding CA which is difficult to obtain without the category theory approach?

Comment: @mathoverflowUser: A weaker version of the question in your comment is whether there are any known results about CA that can be recovered from category theory. A positive answer is shown in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.1220.pdf , namely a general version of the Curtis-Hedlund-Lyndon theorem is obtained from category theory. (The Curtis-Hedlund-Lyndon theorem is important, but not particularly impressive from a technical standpoint.)

Comment: @villesalo thanks fof the pointer